# How can I use savedInstanceState and show text in editText?

Tags: android

I want to save text in a editText and when I rotate the cell phone then it's showed again.

but, "it's showed again" this part doesn't work but, Toast is working.

I thought "setText" is the one...

here is the

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                name = editText.getText().toString();
                showToast("saved : " + name);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            name = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
            showToast("restore : " + name);
            editText.setText("name");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("name", name);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    public void showToast(String data){
        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrapped the variable name in `""` so you're inputting the actual text `name` as a string into the edit text, rather than the contents of that variable. Remove the quotation marks like so:

```
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String text = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
            editText.setText(text);
        }
```

**EDIT**

I would also suggest that you capture the value of the text inside the edit text at the time of `saveInstanceState()`, incase the global 'name' variable happens to be null. Like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        outState.putString("name", text);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't mention that...
I already did it. but, it doesn't work too. Actually nothing remain... either "name" or name

Comment: I have updated my answer with suggestion for how to capture the edittext value at the time of saveInstanceState